# Program prints memory address when converting hexadecimal to an integer

Tags: c, hex

I have seen other solutions to this problem where a pointer is used. I don't understand the workings of a pointer enough to implement them into this program. If the solution requires one, would someone please be able to explain why? I have been trying various things with this program all night and gotten nowhere. I read the relevant text in 'The C Programming Language' book, where the exercise is from. I can't be the only person stumped by this D:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAX 1000

int htoi(char s[]);


main()
{
char line[MAX];
int i, c;
printf("Enter the strig to convert to an integer:");
for(i=0; i<MAX && (c=getchar())!=EOF && c != '\n'; ++i)
    line[i] = c;
int a =0;
a = htoi(line);
printf("%d", a);

}  

int htoi(char s[])
{
int i, n, z;
n=0;
int total = 0;
for(i=0; s[i] != '\0'; ++i)
    {
        if (s[i] == 'a'||s[i] == 'A')
            n = 10;
        else if(s[i] == 'b'||s[i] == 'B')
            n = 11;
        else if(s[i] == 'c'||s[i] == 'C')
            n = 12;
        else if(s[i] == 'd'||s[i] == 'D')
            n = 13;
        else if(s[i] == 'e'||s[i] == 'E')
            n = 14;
        else if(s[i] == 'f'||s[i] == 'F')
            n = 15;
        else
            n = s[i];
        z = n * pow(16, i);
        total = total + z;
    }
return total;
}
```

Comment: `n = s[i];` -> `n = s[i] - '0';`; but otherwise: ***what*** are you trying to do at all? What does this anything to have with pointers?

Comment: Pointers are easy: they're just a variable that contains the memory address of something somewhere else in the system. a real world example of a pointer would be a post-it note on your fridge saying "car keys in bowl by door". the post-it isn't your car keys, but it is telling you where the car keys are so you can go get them.

Comment: I'm trying to convert a hexadecimal string to an integer. I just saw that in a solution someone had used a pointer variable.

Comment: Give us an example of the output you're getting.

Comment: root@debian:/home/tyler/Documents/Programming/Basics# ./a.out
Enter the strig to convert to an integer:1
-2142699683root@debian:/home/tyler/Documents/Programming/Basics#

Comment: Wellcome to SO. From your text it is not at all clear what you are seeking. If you don't understand pointers, go and read about it, there are plenty of resources out there. Or do you want us to comment on your code here? Again SO is not the right place for code review. Please ask specific technical questions. Perhaps first visit the SO FAQ to see what to ask, here, and to the C FAQ to see about the most commonly shared misunderstandings and confusions with C.

Comment: Also, you need to add this `n = s[i] - '0'`

Comment: @TylerPittman Well, because strings are manipulated using pointers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
else
        n = s[i]; // <- n is getting the character code value of S[i]
```

To solve, I suggest to do:

```
else
        n = s[i] - '0';
```

**EDITED:**

You have two problems else:

1. You need to null terminate the line char (your string hasn't '\0')
2. You are inverting the power math (digit more at left are more significants than at right position)

To solve (1), do that:

```
for(i=0; i<MAX && (c=getchar())!=EOF && c != '\n'; ++i)
    line[i] = c;
line[i] = '\0'; // <-- added here
```

To solve (2), do that:

```
int total = 0;
int len = strlen(s) - 1; // <- added here
...
z = n * pow(16, len - i); // <- change here
```

Another way, you can avoid using the expensive pow function by just shifting 4 bits to left as in code bellow:

instead of:

```
z = n * pow(16, i);
total = total + z;
```

do:

```
total <<= 4;  // changed here
total += n;   // and here
```

Comment: Yeah, I agree, just change the answer to reflect that.

Comment: I'm glad you caught that. I did try that, and it still prints a memory address.

Comment: How would I null terminate it? I did invert the power function, but that didn't fix it.

Comment: I understand why you did everything, just not the subtracting one from everything. Do you think you could explain that a bit?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY That is not true. For loop works by first doing initialization, than testing condition, than incrementing, testing condition again and so on. That means that after the condition is FALSE, i will be incremented already (http://www.eng.iastate.edu/efmd/Captures/flow13.gif)

Comment: @TomásBadan I was mistaken You just said it.

Comment: when (i<MAX : false as i == MAX) line[MAX] is Array Out-of-Bounds.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Yeah, I agree with you, there is an Array Out-of-Bounds in the OP codes, but I was not trying to make the code correct. I was trying to show him/her how to change the code to make it works. You spot out an error in his/her code and could have more.

Answer (score 2):

Someone correct me if I am wrong. But you're not putting a null terminator in your char array:

```
for(i=0; i<MAX && (c=getchar())!=EOF && c != '\n'; ++i)
   line[i] = c;
```

Later on, you do

```
for(i=0; s[i] != '\0'; ++i)
```

But since you never appended a null terminator the above for loop will iterate PAST the bounds of the array until it sees a null somewhere on the stack or it segfaults.

you should be doing the following:

```
for(i=0; i<(MAX-1) && (c=getchar())!=EOF && c != '\n'; ++i)
   line[i] = c;
line[i+1] = '\0';
```

Note the `(MAX-1)`

P.S Don't run anything that doesn't require root as root, see: [least privilege principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege)

Comment: Was about to type this!

Comment: That got it to quit printing the memory address. It's giving me a consistent yet incorrect answer to the numbers now. I must have messed up on the math? Why did you take 1 away from the MAX?

Comment: Excuse me for not having logged off root yet, but these are the answers I am getting. root@debian:/home/tyler/Documents/Programming/Basics# ./a.out
Enter the string to convert to an integer:12
33root@debian:/home/tyler/Documents/Programming/Basics# ./a.out
Enter the string to convert to an integer:ab12
8634root@debian:/home/tyler/Documents/Programming/Basics# ./a.out
Enter the string to convert to an integer:ab2
root@debian:/home/tyler/Documents/Programming/Basics# ./a.out
Enter the string to convert to an integer:ab2
698root@debian:/home/tyler/Documents/Programming/Basics#

Comment: `line[i+1]` is erroneuos (http://www.eng.iastate.edu/efmd/Captures/flow13.gif). You can test yourself to see that it gets the next position from the correct place